# Translation issue

Tags: translation

I've many strings that are not translated in the back end even though they are and for years.
Like this one :

[image]

or mix with french like this:

[image]

They often come with the same syntax that seems correct:

> {ts escape="sql" skip="true"}Membership Details{/ts}

How should I improve?

You can see this in the Membership dashboard, for example:
[image]

Comment: I've posted in https://chat.civicrm.org in the Translation channel for assistance. Hopefully someone who knows how the whole translation system works can respond here.

Comment: See answer by @bgm at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/30945/181

Comment: For the "Membership Details" string, on which screen is it? i.e. as a user, how can I reproduce the problem?

Comment: @bgm In the membership dashboard for example, like shown above (I'vve added a screenshot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string displayed in the title of dashboard dashlets is part of the report instance configuration. If you go to the report's configuration, you should be able to change it from there.

If you are using multi-lingual, there is a known limitation on the [roadmap](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/wikis/roadmap) that this field is not multi-lingual in the database schema. It could be, but it's not the case right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bgm, this solved half of my need.
This value can be changed in title.

[image]

I still want to have membership status translated (New, Pending, Current,...) even though they are in CiviMember.

[image]

[image]